# Refused to set unsafe header "Host", ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

although I have set `access-control-allow-origin →*` header in response header form server side, I still can't access the data from the browser, Chrome

I use this code in ionic to load some data:

```
var h = new Headers();
h.set("Host","blahblah.dd");
var arg:RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: h};

return this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8083/api/menu",arg)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(data => { return callback(data) })
```

EDIT:
it is mandatory due to android emulator I have to put Host header. is there any solution in CORS to force set Host header?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in CORS You should make configure your server side to allow Authorization in header.
If you set cross origin request at server then don't need to put header details in api request.

Comment: could you be more specific I made Authorization true and included Host header in Allow-Headers

Comment: Don't put header in api request:

http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8083/api/menu")
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(data => { return callback(data) })

Comment: it is mandatory due to android emulator I have to put Host header. is there any solution in CORS?