# Pass value of variable in function b from function a

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **function A**, I want it to call **function B** using `await`. **function A** has a variable `var imageURL`, how can I call this in **function B** here -
 `"data": "{\n\t\"url\":\"https://i.ibb.co/1b5wYNp/sa.png\"\n\t\n}\n"` in place of hardcoded url.

```js
function A() {
  var encodedImage = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFA";
  console.log("upload pic");
  // Create a root reference
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('image4.jpeg');
  const uploadTastk = firebase.storage().ref().child('image4.jpeg').putString(encodedImage, 'base64', {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  })
  uploadTastk.then(
    (response) => {
      console.log('image upload success')
      console.log(response);
      uploadTastk.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
        console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
        var imageURL = downloadURL;
        await B();
      });
    },
    (failedReason) => {
      console.log('image upload failed')
    }
  )
}

async function B() {
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&recognitionModel=recognition_02&returnRecognitionModel=false&detectionModel=detection_01",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "ocp-apim-subscription-key": "f4446c96ac3440c0b3d51093ce12d558",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "host": "centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "postman-token": "106bce66-4936-9191-5835-c3abb85433e2"
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{\n\t\"url\":\"https://i.ibb.co/1b5wYNp/sa.png\"\n\t\n}\n"
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: use `await B(imageURL)` and `async function B(imageURL) {`. `"data": imageURL`.

Comment: "data": "{\n\t\"url\":\"imageURL\"\n\t\n}\n"     , is this correct ? , i cant remove any other brackets and url word

Comment: in function a , it is saying `await is only valid in async function` , i have added await to function b

Comment: No it is not correct. use `"{\n\t\"url\":\"" + imageURL + "\"\n\t\n}\n"`.

Comment: 400 (Bad Request) ,  `"data": "{\n\t\"url\":\"" + url + "\"\n\t\n}\n"`   this line is not correct

Comment: You no need `\n\t`. Simply use like `"data" : '{ "url" : "' + url + '" }`. It will should work or your existing code `"data": "{\n\t\"url\":\"https://i.ibb.co/1b5wYNp/sa.png\"\n\t\n}\n"` should also throwing same error.

Comment: thanks it worked , i can accept your answer if you wish to answer

Comment: @Karan I am deleting my answer since we are achieving the same goal to work somehow you can go ahead and answer. if you wish to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `B(imageURL)` and add parameter to `B` as `async function B(imageURL)`.

Update your `"data"` value assignment to be like below.

```
"data" : '{ "url" : "' + url + '" }
```

Moreover you can use [`Template literals (Template strings)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to build your string like below.

```
"data" : `{ "url" : "${url}" }`
```

```js
let url = "https://i.ibb.co/1b5wYNp/sa.png";

let data = '{ "url" : "' + url + '" }';
console.log(data);

// using Template literals (Template strings)
data = `{ "url" : "${url}" }`;
console.log(data);
```

Comment: everything working but it is giving 1 error saying `Refused to set unsafe header "host"`

Comment: That could be another question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204417/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-host-ionic,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182712/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-origin-when-using-xmlhttprequest-of-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

As imgeUrl is a String version of a JSON data you can pass it through `JSON.parse` function to have a Javascript object which you can manipulate easily in your code like this

```js
let downloadURL = "{\n\t\"url\":\"https://i.ibb.co/1b5wYNp/sa.png\"\n\t\n}\n";
let parsedData = JSON.parse(downloadURL);

console.log(parsedData);
```

after parsing the `downloadURL` variable you can have access to the url by using the `url` key.

Also specify that `B` function take a `url` parameter so you can call that function like this

```
await B(parsedData.url);

async function B(url); // the definition of the B function with url parameter
```

and in the settings of your AJAX call you'll set

```
"data": { url }
```

or you can passed the `parsedData` variable as parameter

```
await B(parsedData);


async function B(data) { //... } // the definition of the B function with data parameter
```

and in the settings of your AJAX call you'll set

```
"data": data
```